# how do I protect an sql entry from a "meta" injection?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I have a site which allows the user to save images. I sanitize mysql inserts with 'mysql_real_escape_string', but someone went and entered a meta with a content redirect in his image description, so that whenever our site loads (loading the latest images as well), it redirects.

How can I sanitize my strings or sql queries to protect against that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use framework that protects from MySQL Injections.

Comment: `strip_tags()` on input and `htmlspecialchars()` on output are a good start - also, if accepting image uploads, make sure you use GD to copy the pixel data from the uploaded file to a new one, or it is possible for malicious code to be hidden inside the image itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the common defenses against XSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129899/what-are-the-common-defenses-against-xss)

Comment: Also, welcome to the world of XSS and CSRF (Google them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is couple of things you can do

1. Use [`strip_tags()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)
2. Use `mysqli_*` function instead of `mysql_`
3. Use parameterized queries/prepared statments.
4. If possible consider using PHP Frameworks.
5. Convert special character into their respective [`htmlentities()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: 2 and 3 are irrelevant to the question and 4 is too vague to be helpful.

Comment: I tried different things, and for my particular circumstance strip_tags worked the best. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For this particular example, you could have avoided it by using [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) when outputting the data:

```
<?php
$str = "A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";

// Outputs: A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str);

// Outputs: A &#039;quote&#039; is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
?>
```

The catch is that it would destroy pretty much *any* HTML from being used in the stuff you are saving. If you are trying to allow certain tags and disallow others, it quickly gets a lot more complicated.

Comment: For a *lot more complicated* things you could recommend [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_real_escape_string` is only used to prevent sql injection.

To prevent XSS, you need to use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or [htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to sanitize the html content.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using the `htmlspecialchars();` everytime before putting anything from the database and before you submit the user input to the database use prepared statements + `htmlspecialchars();`[optional]