# Should I use htmlentities() on all output? (preventing XSS attacks)

Tags: php, mysql, security, xss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best practices for avoiding xss attacks in a PHP site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328/what-are-the-best-practices-for-avoiding-xss-attacks-in-a-php-site)
>   [What are the common defenses against XSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129899/what-are-the-common-defenses-against-xss)

I'm trying to make a PHP application I've written secure and have a question about escaping output. I switched to using prepared statements with PDO once I learned doing so would prevent SQL injections, and it seems that the other main type of attack is XSS. I build the output for my pages like this (assume the variables have data from the database in them):

```
$output = '';

$output .= '
<div style="float: left; width: 800px;">
    <span>Name:</span><span> ' . $name . '</span>
    <span>Address:</span><span>' . $addr . '</span>
    <span>Time:</span><span>' . time() . '</span>
</div>';

$output .='[lots more html]';
```

So, my question is, should I use `htmlentities()` around every piece of data from the database being output (a typical page has dozens, some possibly hundreds, of variables from the database being output)?

Comment: use `http://htmlpurifier.org/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two benefits to using [`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/htmlentities):

- XSS prevention
- Converting special characters to proper HTML entities, for example it converts the copyright character to `&copy;`. In HTML content you should use the appropriate HTML entity instead of inserting a raw special character.

For XSS prevention, you could use [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars) instead, but it will only convert some basic characters to HTML entities, namely quotes, ampersand and the less than/greater than characters.

In answer to your question, you should use `htmlentities()` when outputting any content that could contain user input or special characters.

Answer (score 0):

`htmlspecialchars()` is more than enough. `htmlentities` is for different use, not preventing XSS.