# Handling a HTML WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: php, html, wysiwyg

I've constructed a simple, light-weight WYSIWYG HTML editor with the use of contentEditable="true", inserting HTML tags via javascript.

It all works great, except I don't know the best way to submit, validate, and insert the input into the database. I'm concerned that someone might insert their own tags and mess up the output.

My best idea so far is to convert all valid tags into BBCode with PHP just before inserting the input into the batabase, and then clear all the other tags. Is this conventional?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the common defenses against XSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129899/what-are-the-common-defenses-against-xss)

Comment: @Quentin : I already strip the other HTML tags. I'm just curious how I should handle the tags which I want preserve. That doesn't seem to answer it, but thanks anyway!

Comment: You (a) Don't allow elements/attributes that can "mess up the output" and (b) as per the duplicate question use "a real parser" that acts as a "validator" (which prevents mismatched start/end tags)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.
Another approach would be to convert your tags already in your WYSIWYG editor. Either way does not help you around "never trust user input data" so you have to validate that code anyway. You have to assume that it can be corrupted.

Comment: Thanks! That's just what I was looking for. I least I know I'm on the right track. :)

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably want to run it through something like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) to ensure you strip out any malicious code.

I'm not sure if HTML Purifier already does it, but you would also want to use `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` to strip out any database attack-related code before storing the data.

Comment: Thanks, but what about the tags I want to preserve and effect the output? I suppose searching for those tags before outputing, as opposed to converting them to BBCode, would be better.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. When you `post` your WYSIWYG form you'd run it through HTML Purifier and also use `htmlspecialchars` to encode any symbols before storing it. Then when displaying the data you'd use `htmlspecialchars_decode` to turn the encoded symbols back into valid HTML.

Comment: Oh, I see! I'm sorry, this is a new area for me, and I'm not familiar with all the terminology. But I think I understand it now. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. To try and make it a bit clearer, what you'd be doing here is: 1) let the user submit the WYSIWYG form. 2) Encode and sanitize the data before storing it on the server. 3) Decoding the now-sanitized data before presenting it back to the user. This way you (hopefully) rule out server-side and client-side exploits. :-)

Comment: Oh well that simplifies everything :) It's just a matter of encoding > Insert > Decode > Output. Thank you.

Comment: `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` won't do anything to protect the database.  Use `mysqli_real_escape_string` for that.