# How to filter XSS out but still allow basic formatting tags

Tags: php, html, editor, xss, sanitization

I am working on a website that allows people to enter html formatted content using an editor.

However, I am concerned about XSS injections. The editor obviously filters information on the client side using Javascripts, but I hardly can trust that given that it's good practice to trust nothing from the client side.

I want to be able to whitelist certain tags such as:

```
<br> <img src=""> <p> <b>
```

but still perform a  secure filter of the inputs against XSS attacks.

I considered using http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php but I've noticed that the img tag is one of the XSS hackers' favourites.

Is it possible to make a function that would do this? Would it be secure?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the common defenses against XSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129899/what-are-the-common-defenses-against-xss)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/):

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();

// the tags and attributes you want to allow
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'br,img[src],p,b');

$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

print $purifier->purify($inputHtml);
```

---

Another possible solution is to load your HTML into [`DomDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), remove unwanted elements or attributes and get the updated HTML

Answer (score 0):

I would still prefer BB codes. You can find a decent BB parser class at http://phpclasses.org