# Retain textbox value

Tags: php

My Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A BASIC HTML FORM</title>

<?PHP
if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
}
?>
</head>
<body>
<Form name ="form1" Method ="POST" Action ="basicForm.php">
<Input Type = "text" Value ="<?PHP print $username ;?>" Name ="username">
<Input Type = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" Value = "Login">
</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

Problem: The PHP code gets displayed in the textbox instead of the actual value

[image: Demonstration]

Comment: That sounds like the server doesn't have PHP installed, or configured correctly as the code is being interpreted as plain text

Comment: Try `<?= $username; ?>` or `<?php echo $username; ?>`.

Comment: May be your file is not php

Comment: @Pietu1998 — Why? They are all equivalent to the existing code.

Comment: @Quentin Well, an old version or something could not work e.g. with uppercase `<?PHP ?>`. And also it looks better :)

Comment: why `<?PHP` is uppercased? Is it configured this way? Default is `<?php`, no?

Comment: @Pietu1998 — Did they *change* `<?php` to be case insensitive? Or are you guessing?

Comment: @CORRUPT — It's case insensitive. Lower case is convention, not default.

Answer (score 3):

That syntax is correct (albeit vulnerable to [XSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129899/what-are-the-common-defenses-against-xss)).

If it doesn't work, then you aren't using a server that supports PHP for the file you are loading.

PHP, on the WWW, only works when the page is accessed:

- Through a web server
- That has PHP installed
- That knows that the file you are loading contains PHP and should be processed by the PHP engine (this is usually done by giving it a `.php` file extension).

**Update**: You have edited your question to include a screen grab. This confirms this answer. You are trying to load the PHP from your file system directly into your browser (with a `file:///` URI). You need to access it through a web server (with an `http://` URI).

---

As @CORRUPT points out in a comment. You don't give `$username` a default value, so you will get an error if the POST data isn't set. I suggest setting it to an empty string before the `if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {` line.

Comment: `<?php print isset($username) ? $username : ''; ?>` -> still need to be fixed. In OP's version `<?PHP` instead of `<?php`.

Comment: @Binoj Also make sure your file is called `something.php` and not `something.html`

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A BASIC HTML FORM</title>

<?PHP
if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
}else{
$username='';
}
?>
</head>
<body>
<Form name ="form1" Method ="POST" Action ="basicForm.php">
<Input Type = "text" Value ="<?PHP print $username ;?>" Name ="username">
<Input Type = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" Value = "Login">
</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this function in the php block:

```
function prepopulate($name) { 
 if(isset($_POST[$name])) { 
  return $_POST[$name]; 
 } 
 else { 
  return ""; 
 } 
}
```

and then in the HTML part

```
<FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="POST" ACTION = "">
<input name="fname" type="text" value="<?php echo prepopulate('fname');?>">
<input name="lname" type="text" value="<?php echo prepopulate('lname');?>">
</FORM>
```

You just have to pass the name of the textbox to the function prepopulate to retain it after form submit.