# Unable to redirect with htmlspecialchars() on urlencode()

Tags: php, xss

Am trying to redirect user to `requested_page` after login, After googling i tried this code

**link to login page**

```
echo "<a href='/login.php?ref=". urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ."'>login</a>";
```

and in **login.php**

```
    if ($_GET['ref'] != '') {
        $url = $_GET['ref'];
    } else {
        $url = "/";
    }

if ($user->login($username, $password)) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header("location:http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$url);
            exit();
        }
```

> Above method works fine, But it is vulnerable to **XSS**
>
> `login.php?ref=<script>alert(%27Malicious%20content%27)</script>`

so i added `htmlspecialchars()` like this

```
    if ($_GET['ref'] != '') {
        $url = htmlspecialchars($_GET['ref']);
    } else {
        $url = "/";
    }
```

but it is not redirected, rather it shows `404 error`

any help how do i protect from **XSS attack**

Comment: `echo '<a href="/login.php?ref=' . htmlspecialchars(urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) . '">login</a>';`
and the redirection part: `header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_GET['ref']);`

Comment: @RolandStarke doesn't work still i see `XSS` script

Comment: The code outputs `<a href='/login.php?ref=login.php%3Fref%3D%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%2527Malicious%2520content%2527%29%3C%2Fscript%3E'>login</a>`. Where's the XSS vulnerability there?

Comment: when i try `http://localhost:8000/login.php?ref=%3Cscript%3Ealert(%27Malicious%20content%27)%3C/script%3E` i see `alert` this is my problem.

Comment: @Quentin here is the live demo http://www.safebrowser.tk/login?ref=%3Cscript%3Ealert(%27Malicious%20content%27)%3C/script%3E when i try `http://www.safebrowser.tk/login?ref=%3Cscript%3Ealert(%27Malicious%20content%27)%3C/script%3E`

Comment: @sanojlawrence — Here's the code by itself: https://jsbin.com/lubeliwiqa/1/edit?html,output — whatever the vulnerability is, it isn't in the code you supplied. `http://www.safebrowser.tk/login` must have different code.

Comment: Yeah. The vulnerability is at `<h6 class="small text-black-50">Log in with social media account or email</h6>
                                www.safebrowser.tk<script>alert('Malicious content')</script>                            </div>` and nothing to do with the link you have in the question.

Comment: @Quentin yes that is what am asking i want to protect `login.php` `$_GET`.

Comment: You apply protection to **the part of the code which is vulnerable** and not a different part of the code. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129899/what-are-the-common-defenses-against-xss

Comment: @Quentin want to show how i pass `?ref='value'` i link.

Comment: That's not where the code is vulnerable. The code is vulnerable just after the `<h6>`. You have to fix the code where it is vulnerable.

Comment: @Quentin so no need to add `htmlspecialchars($_GET['ref']);` the problem is with this part `<?= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$url ?>` i just added this for `debugg`. `<h6 class="small text-black-50">Log in with social media account or email</h6>
                                <?= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$url ?>`

Comment: If you've deleted the code with the XSS vulnerability just after the `<h6>` then the XSS vulnerability is gone and you don't need to do anything more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally solved.

Error was created from debugging code

```
if ($_GET['ref'] != '') {
    $url = htmlspecialchars($_GET['ref']);
} else {
    $url = "/";
}

<h6 class="small text-black-50">Log in with social media account or email</h6>
 <?= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$url ?>
```

this created a issue

```
<?= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$url ?>
```

and removed this line and solved.